# I'm trying to join 3 tables in node.js using sequelize but having trouble. What is the problem with my code?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Newer to Node.js any advice would be appreciated!  Trying to join 3 tables with a common key but getting the error...

react_devtools_backend.js:4026 [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown column 'google_responsive_descriptions.googleTextAdId' in 'on clause', Location: [object Object], Path: listGoogleTextAds

googleResponsiveAds.js file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const googleResponsiveAds = sequelize.define(
    "google_responsive_headlines",
    {
      responsive_headlines: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      responsive_path_1: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      responsive_path_2: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "google_responsive_headlines"
    }
  );
  //googleResponsiveAds.associate = () => {};
    googleResponsiveAds.associate = function (models) {
    googleResponsiveAds.belongsTo(models.google_text_ads, { foreignKey: "ad_id" });
  }
  return googleResponsiveAds;
};
```

googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds.js file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds = sequelize.define(
    "google_responsive_descriptions",
    {
      responsive_descriptions: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "google_responsive_descriptions"
    }
  );
  //googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds.associate = () => {};
    googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds.associate = function (models) {
    googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds.belongsTo(models.google_text_ads, { foreignKey: "ad_id" });
  }
  return googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds;
};
```

googleTextAds.js file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const googleTextAds = sequelize.define(
    "google_text_ads",
    {
      headline_pt_1: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      headline_pt_2: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      headline_pt_3: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      final_url: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      display_url: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      status: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      type: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      description1: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      description2: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      path1: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      path2: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      ad_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "google_text_ads"
    }
  );
  //googleTextAds.associate = () => {};
  googleTextAds.associate = function (models) {
    googleTextAds.hasMany(models.google_responsive_headlines, { sourceKey: 'ad_id' })
    googleTextAds.hasMany(models.google_responsive_descriptions, { sourceKey: 'ad_id' });
  };
  return googleTextAds;
};
```

Here is the section of the queries/google.js

```
{
    key: "listGoogleTextAds",
    prototype:
      "(customer_id: Int, start_date: String, end_date: String): [GoogleTextAds]",
    run: async args => {
      const allIds = await google_text_ads
      .findAll({
          attributes: [
            "ad_id",
            "date",
            "impressions",
            "clicks",
            "cost"
          ],
          include: [
          {
            model: google_responsive_descriptions,
            as: 'google_responsive_descriptions',
            required: true,
            attributes: [
              "ad_id",
              "responsive_descriptions"
            ],
          },
          {
            model: google_responsive_headlines,
            as: 'google_responsive_headlines',
            attributes: [
              "ad_id",
              "responsive_headlines",
              "responsive_path_1",
              "responsive_path_2"
            ]
          }
        ],
        where: {
          customer_id: args.customer_id,
          date: {
            [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
            [Op.lte]: args.end_date
          },
          status: {
            [Op.in]: ["ENABLED"]
          },
          type: {
            [Op.in]: ["EXPANDED_TEXT_AD", "RESPONSIVE_SEARCH_AD"]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

EDIT:  Here's my query

```
export const LIST_GOOGLE_TEXT_ADS = gql`
  query listGoogleTextAds(
    $customer_id: Int!
    $start_date: String!
    $end_date: String!
  ) {
    listGoogleTextAds(
      customer_id: $customer_id
      start_date: $start_date
      end_date: $end_date
    ) {
      ad_id
      type
      headline_pt_1
      headline_pt_2
      headline_pt_3
      description1
      description2
      path1
      path2
      status
      final_url
      display_url
      impressions
      clicks
      cost
    }
  }
`;
```

and my models...

```
type GoogleTextAds {
    ad_id: Int
    type: String
    headline_pt_1: String
    headline_pt_2: String
    headline_pt_3: String
    description1: String
    description2: String
    path1: String
    path2: String
    final_url: String
    display_url: String
    status: String
    impressions: Int
    clicks: Int
    cost: Float
  }
  type GoogleResponsiveAds{
    ad_id: Int
    responsive_headlines: String
    responsive_path_1: String
    responsive_path_2: String
  }
  type GoogleResponsiveDescriptionsAds{
    ad_id: Int
    responsive_descriptions: String
  }
```

here is the query I am trying to replicate...

```
            SELECT distinct google_responsive_headlines.responsive_headlines,
           google_responsive_headlines.responsive_path_1,
           google_responsive_headlines.responsive_path_2,
           google_responsive_descriptions.responsive_descriptions,
           google_text_ads.date,
           google_text_ads.clicks,
           google_text_ads.cost,
           google_text_ads.impressions,
           google_text_ads.ad_id,
           google_text_ads.status,
           google_text_ads.final_url,
           google_text_ads.create_time
      FROM irene_db.google_text_ads
     inner JOIN irene_db.google_responsive_headlines ON google_responsive_headlines.ad_id = google_text_ads.ad_id
     inner JOIN irene_db.google_responsive_descriptions ON google_responsive_descriptions.ad_id = google_text_ads.ad_id
      where google_text_ads.customer_id = 144 and google_text_ads.date = '2022-06-09' and 
      google_responsive_headlines.customer_id = 144 and google_responsive_headlines.date = '2022-06-09' and
       google_responsive_descriptions.customer_id = 144 and google_responsive_descriptions.date = '2022-06-09';
```

EDIT2:  Where associate gets called...

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const db = {};
let sequelize;

const { DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME } = process.env;

sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: DB_HOST
});
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(
    file =>
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
  )
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

EDIT 3:
After boc4life's code suggestions I'm now at least getting graphql to attempt the query.  But it's using the wrong field name in the join on section.  Here's the query it built...

```
    SELECT 
        `google_text_ads`.`id`,
        `google_text_ads`.`ad_id`,
        `google_text_ads`.`date`,
        `google_text_ads`.`impressions`,
        `google_text_ads`.`clicks`,
        `google_text_ads`.`cost`,
        `google_responsive_descriptions`.`id` AS `google_responsive_descriptions.id`,
        `google_responsive_descriptions`.`responsive_descriptions` AS `google_responsive_descriptions.responsive_descriptions`,
        `google_responsive_headlines`.`id` AS `google_responsive_headlines.id`,
        `google_responsive_headlines`.`responsive_headlines` AS `google_responsive_headlines.responsive_headlines`,
        `google_responsive_headlines`.`responsive_path_1` AS `google_responsive_headlines.responsive_path_1`,
        `google_responsive_headlines`.`responsive_path_2` AS `google_responsive_headlines.responsive_path_2`
    FROM
        `google_text_ads` AS `google_text_ads`
            INNER JOIN
        `google_responsive_descriptions` AS `google_responsive_descriptions` ON `google_text_ads`.`ad_id` = `google_responsive_descriptions`.`googleTextAdId`
            INNER JOIN
        `google_responsive_headlines` AS `google_responsive_headlines` ON `google_text_ads`.`ad_id` = `google_responsive_headlines`.`googleTextAdId`
    WHERE
        `google_text_ads`.`customer_id` = 142
            AND (`google_text_ads`.`date` >= '2022-05-17'
            AND `google_text_ads`.`date` <= '2022-06-17')
            AND `google_text_ads`.`status` IN ('ENABLED')
            AND `google_text_ads`.`type` IN ('EXPANDED_TEXT_AD' , 'RESPONSIVE_SEARCH_AD');
```

Comment: Show how you register models and associations

Comment: @Anatoly I've updated my code with your request.

Comment: I didn't find where you call `associate` method for each model. Also I don;t get why you define two duplicated `associate` functions for each model. there sould be only one per a model with all needed associations

Comment: @Anatoly Forgive my ignorance, only had a year with node.  I believe the last edit I made shows where associate is called.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **tableName** defined while defining the table structure to access the model while creating associations.

Example: instead of

> **models.googleTextAds**

do

> **models.google_text_ads**

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now but I'm still not getting the right data.  I've updated my code with more info.

Answer (score 1):

What jumps out to me is all of those nested includes. Since you are joining the Headlines and Descriptions tables on the Text_Ads table, I believe all you should need here is the one include array containing two objects, one for Headlines and one for Descriptions.

Currently you have Headlines nested under Descriptions, which won't work because Descriptions does not have an association with Headlines directly defined. You also have an include of Text_Ads nested inside of Descriptions, which should WORK, but should be unnecessary since that is the model you are calling findAll() on. You can bring the Text_Ads attributes you are querying for out into that parent object as a sibling of include. Something like this looks like a good starting point for getting the query cleaned up. I have also removed a bunch of the unnecessary sequelize.col() that you had in your initial post.

```
const allIds = await google_text_ads
    .findAll({
        attributes: [
          "ad_id",
          [sequelize.fn("max", sequelize.col("date")), "date"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("impressions")), "impressions"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("clicks")), "clicks"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("cost")), "cost"]            
        ],
        include: [
        {
          model: Models.google_responsive_descriptions,
          as: 'googleResponsiveDescriptionsAds',
          required: true,
          attributes: [
            "ad_id",
            "responsive_descriptions"
          ],
        },
        {
          model: Models.google_responsive_headlines,
          as: 'googleResponsiveAds',
          attributes: [
            "ad_id",
            "responsive_headlines",
            "responsive_path_1",
            "responsive_path_2"
          ]
        }
      ],
      where: {
        customer_id: args.customer_id,
        date: {
          [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
          [Op.lte]: args.end_date
        },
        status: {
          [Op.in]: ["ENABLED"]
        },
        type: {
          [Op.in]: ["EXPANDED_TEXT_AD", "RESPONSIVE_SEARCH_AD"]
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: After taking another pass at looking at this, I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do with those sum and max functions. Those don't appear to be in the raw SQL query that you are trying to replicate. Seems like you can probably just turn those into strings like "date", "impressions", "clicks", and "cost"

Comment: Thanks @boc4life.  I implemented your code suggestion and it compiles but throwing a graphql error in the console...  [GraphQL error]: Message: Table 'irene_db.ad_id' doesn't exist, Location: [object Object], Path: listGoogleTextAds

Comment: Also, graphql is attempting the query now.  I put the query it built in the 3rd edit.  It's just using a field name instead of the included table names.

Comment: Are you building the tables from migrations or from sequelize.sync()? Does the ad_id junction table exist? The { through: 'ad_id' } in your models' belongToMany associations indicates that Sequelize should query a table called ad_id which links the other 3 models together. From the start I've been curious about that database architecture, perhaps you need to re-design the associations.

Comment: If the structure of the tables should be that there is one "parent" table of Ads, then tables of Headlines and Descriptions associated to those ads (What it kind of looks like to me). The associations on the Ads table should be hasMany or hasOne, and the associations on Headlines and Descriptions should be belongsTo

Comment: Ok, I've made those changes and updated the query graphql built.  It's really close to running!!!  It's using id for the join but I don't understand where that's coming from...  `google_text_ads`.`id` = `google_responsive_headlines`.`ad_id`